# Twig extension - symfony2 environment

Tags: php, symfony, twig

im trying to write an extension that works will depend on the environment. How to retrieve the name of the current environment inside the extension class? What is best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to inject the parameter in your extension constructor.

Either, you may refer to current envinroment in twig templates as `app.environment`.