# Get Symfony2 environment in bundle Extension

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony2 bundle extension my `services.yml` is being loaded

```
$loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
$loader->load('services.yml');
```

However I want to load different services config per environment (eg: a different one for tests).

Most of the examples I've found for getting the current environment is for access within Controllers (eg: `$this->get('kernel')->getEnvironment()`), however Controller based access is not possible in Extensions.

According to [Twig extension - symfony2 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307815/twig-extension-symfony2-environment) the environment can be constructor injected however I'm not sure how my bundle extension is registered/instantiated by Symfony so not sure how to have the enviroment injected (the only references I find via grep are in the cache files, which isn't too helpful).

How can I either specify a different services YAML file to be loaded per env in config, or at least find out the environment so that I can code my Extension class to load the correct file?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Normally, while loading your services, your method prototype should be

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container).
```

then you can access your environment doing a

```
$env = $container->getParameter("kernel.environment")
```

and then test the $env to see in which environment type you are.

Something like

```
if ("dev" == $env) {
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('devServices.yml');
}
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you have your controller as a service you can inject ```%kernel.environment%```

Comment: better approach :)

Answer (score 12):

```
echo $this->container->get(‘kernel’)->getEnvironment();
```

in the latest version (2.5)

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little more explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.