# Disable listener in dev environment

Tags: symfony

Can I somehow configure a service/listener to not load/listen in certain environments?

I know I can inject the `kernel.environment` in the service and check that in every method. However, that doesn't really seem elegant :)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can move the listener service to another config file, for example services_dev.yml  and load it or not depending on the environment in you bundles extension class' load function in

```
...Bundle/DependencyInjection/...Extension.php
```

depending on how is your project configured as described here

[Get Symfony2 environment in bundle Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563769/get-symfony2-environment-in-bundle-extension)